# Edit custom List View when current view is on page 2+ - no results shown

Tags: custom-view

Is this a known issue, with salesforce custom views.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Log into Salesforce.
2. Pick or create a custom view where pagination occurs.
3. Now goto the third or fourth page by clicking Next button in the bottom.
4. Now Click to edit this view.
5. where intention is to narrow down the result by increase the filtering criterion so the results appear in first page.
6. Save it.
7. Voila No result is displayed.

**Solution**: 
After looking at the URL, I found out that
there was a sticky parameter that stuck to the page even after the view got changed seems a perpetual bug in SalesForce.
For reference
**Parameter**: &page=$PageNo
just removing it will resolve the problem.

Comment: I met that issue 3 years ago. That's because of pagination param is still in the url. as long as you remove it -- it will automatically start displaying from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

There is a sticky parameter that sticks to the page even after the view gets updated, seems like a perpetual bug in SalesForce.
For reference
**Parameter**: &page=$PageNo
just remove it and resolve the problem.